# admin and user login

Tags: php, mysqli

```
require_once('includes/user_config.php');

//check if already logged in move to home page
if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: index.php'); } 

//process login form if submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    if($user->login($username,$password)){ 

        $status = 0;
        header('Location: house/admincp.php');
        exit;

    }
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($user->login($username,$password)){ 
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $status = '1';
        header('Location: house/memberpage.php');
        exit;

    }else {
        $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
    }
```

```
<div class="row">
```

### Please Login

Back to home page

---

```
            <?php
            //check for any errors
            if(isset($error)){
                foreach($error as $error){
                    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$error.'</p>';
                }
            }

            if(isset($_GET['action'])){

                //check the action
                switch ($_GET['action']) {
                    case 'active':
                        echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Your account is now active you may now log in.</h2>";
                        break;
                    case 'reset':
                        echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Please check your inbox for a reset link.</h2>";
                        break;
                    case 'resetAccount':
                        echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Password changed, you may now login.</h2>";
                        break;
                }

            }


            ?>
        <!- Username starts here ->
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="User Name" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['username']; } ?>" tabindex="1">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
                     <a href='reset.php'>Forgot your Password?</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="5"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pls i want to get a correct the code to connect to either admin with status 0 or user with status 1

Comment: This is just a code dump. What is your question?

Comment: @AsikaAbulu Put your question in the question, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an `if()` statement for `$status`.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
if($user->login($username,$password)){ 
    if ($status == 0) {
        header('Location: house/admincp.php');
    } else {
        header('Location: house/memberpage.php');
    }
    exit();
} else {
    $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
}
```

But it seems strange to me that you let the user specify whether they're an admin or user in the login form. You probably should return the status from `$user->login();`, which can get it from the database.

Comment: Thank you for the response,am very new to coding but all logging go to admincp.php .Both users and admin

Comment: Or rather please help me,which other way can i correct the code to work.Please help me!

Comment: Could you add the login form to the question, so we can see what's in `$_POST['status']`?

Comment: No status on the login form,its just the username and password then submit

Comment: Then what is `$_POST['status']` supposed to be?

Comment: If there's no `status` in the form, how do you know if the user is an admin? Does `$user->login()` return this information?

Comment: its a way to redirect admin to admincp.php or user to memberpage.php using 1 or 0.i only want to achive user to login to member page and admin login to admin only.

Comment: on the database i made status with character format enum 0,1 so with that all users can login with status 1 but i have set the admin to be zero already.

Comment: $_POST['status'] was on trials i was making to get the login successful with both admincp.php and memberpage.php.I was only trying everything and that came up

Comment: OK, so it's in the database, but how do you get it into your application? Does `$user->login()` get it from the database? Do you have a method in the `User` class that returns it?

Comment: yes on the user config file.//include the user class, pass in the database connection
include('classes/user.php');
include('classes/phpmailer/mail.php');
$user = new User($db);

Comment: You're not answering the question. How do you find out whether `$user` is a user or admin?

Comment: Is there something like `$user->userType()` that returns this?

Comment: no i dont have $user->userType().This was the code is modified https://daveismyname.blog/blog/login-and-registration-system-with-php

Comment: So you need to add a function like that, to return whether the user is an admin or not. Then just call it and send the appropriate header.

Comment: please how will i do that sir,please assist me

Comment: I have no idea. I don't know the schema for your database, or the design of your `User` class. You say it's based on that blog, but there's nothing about admin users there. It seems like it should be quite simple, you write a query that gets the user type of the user, and check whether it's the admin type.